# How does Charles proxy work when proxying SSL traffic?

Tags: android, ssl, encryption, charles-proxy

When I want to view SSL traffic which is being proxied through Charles I need to have [an SSL certificate from Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/getssl/) installed on the smartphone. Why it's needed and how it's possible for Charles to decrypt and then encrypt again the data routed through it?

I imagine it in the way that if some smartphone app uses SSL then:

- the data is encrypted (by the app? by the OS' network layers?) then
- the encrypted data is sent to the world and
- the encrypted data is intercepted by Charles
- Charles gets the encrypted data and **what now?**

How does it know how to decrypt the encrypted data? And how does it know how to encrypt the decrypted data again to send it finally to where it was originally targeted?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, what I'm going to post here is just how **I think SSL proxying with Charles works**, but I don't have any solid base to ensure my answer is correct. In fact, it would be great if someone from the Charles Proxy team could help us on this.

The point is that when your application performs an HTTPS request to a site firstly it has to go through the Charles Proxy (don't forget it is a proxy!). At this moment, Charles connects to the https site by using **the site's** public key to encrypt and decrypt data, as if it was a regular browser or application.

So at this moment Charles has the response from your https request unencrypted, and this must be passed to your application, but your application is expecting encrypted data, so Charles has to encrypt it again so your application (i.e.: your browser) doesn't complain about an uncrypted https response. To do so, Charles uses his own certificate (public + private key pair), encrypts your data and sends it back to your application.

Finally, your application receives this data encrypted by Charles. Your application won't know how to decrypt it unless you give him the public key of the certificate (this is done by "installing" the certificate on your application/browser/android device/etc.).

This is how I think all the SSL proxying works with Charles.

It would be really great if someone could contribute to this answer!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a creator of [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io), which is a macOS web debugging proxy like Charles Proxy, so I might have the insight and experience to answer your questions.

1. When you start Proxyman/Charles, it will open a server at IP=127.0.0.1, port 9090, or 8080. It also overrides the HTTP/HTTPS Proxy in Network -> Wifi -> Advanced -> Proxies tab.

It's essential to make sure all traffic will go through Proxyman/Charles server.

If it's an iPhone, you have to manually set a Proxy config in the Setting app. Guideline: https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/ios-device

2. As soon as the client (macOS) or iOS app (iOS devices) makes an HTTPS request with a Proxy Config. The first request is a CONNECT request to Proxyman/Charles Server.
3. Proxyman accepts it and returns 200 OK Status.
4. Your app and Proxyman server would perform SSL Handshake.

In order to make it successful, you have to install and trust Proxyman/Charles CA Certificate, which is a self-signed certificate.

- For macOS: Install & trust in System Keychain.app
- For iOS: You have to visit http://proxy.man/ssl (or http://chls.pro/ssl)

4.1. Proxyman extracts the Host key in the previous CONNECT request and starts fetching the actual certificate server.

4.2. Proxyman parses the certificate and gets all certificate information, such as Org, Name, Common Name, Subject Alternative Name (DNS and IP Address), etc

From what I know, Charles Proxy doesn't perform this step. It just generates a basic leaf certificate. Some clients can detect the missing data in the leaf certificate and reject it.

4.3. Proxyman starts generating a leaf certificate by using Proxyman CA Certificate. It's important to construct the same certificate that has the same information from the server.

If it's a macOS/iOS app, make sure the certificate is complied with a new [security requirement from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176). Otherwise, it might be rejected.

This step can be implemented by using OpenSSL or BoringSSL library.

4.4. Proxyman server sends the leaf certificate back to the client.
4.5. The client will verify the leaf certificate and it's passed. Because the CA Certificate is trusted in their system and it passes some basic evaluation, such as:

- Common Name and DNS name must equal the Host
- It's not expired
- Use acceptance encrypting algorithms
- and more

5. At this point, the SSL Handshake is complete, and the client starts sending the HTTPS Request.
6. Proxyman now acts as a Server, so Proxyman can decrypt the read the HTTPS Request in plain text.
7. Proxyman now acts as a Client and connects to the server. Then start sending a request. This step is really easy because the server's certificate is signed by a well-known CA certificate.
8. As soon as Proxyman receives a Response, Proxyman reads it and sends it back to the client.
9. The client receives the Response and works as normal.

Since Proxyman can see the Request/Response in plain text, it can display on the app or performs few debugging tools to modify the data, such as [Map Local](https://docs.proxyman.io/advanced-features/map-local), [Scripting](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/script), [Breakpoint](https://docs.proxyman.io/advanced-features/breakpoint), etc.

---

It's a long answer and I hope that can answer your concern.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! Tran, what do you mean by "leaf certificate"? Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

What Charles does is basically a [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). That's why you have to install it's certificate on the device you are using.

Usually when a device and server communicate via ssl/tls, the request and responses are encrypted using the server's certificate. This means that someone who intercepts the traffic can not read it since it's encrypted with the server's certificate. But since you installed Charles' certificate (meaning your device trusts it) on your device and you set it up to communicate to the server via the proxy, Charles is able to decrypt the traffic.

The steps would look like this:

1. client and server do a key exchange (however since Charles is in the middle, they exchange keys with Charles)
2. client sends an encrypted request to the server (however it uses the key from Charles)
3. Charles intercepts the request
4. Charles decrypts the request and that's what you see
5. Charles encrypts the request with the server's key
6. Charles sends it to the server

And the same happens for responses.